# ojdbc6 driver keeping soft references in tomcat

Tags: java, performance, tomcat7, ojdbc

My application on startup fires lot of queries to pump up the initial cache.

At this point, profiling code using JProfiler suggests that soft references are maintained by ojdbc6 driver. As a result, my initial JVM size increases to a higher value which gives me a performance hit if any request are received by tomcat.

This occupied JVM size comes down to almost half of its size after a considerable amount (1 hr in my case) even if no http request are received by the server.

To counter that, I configured tomcat with context paramters as          `factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"` and `jdbcInterceptors="StatementCache(max=100)"`

Still I could see soft references maintained by ojdbc6 driver using JProfiler.

Question: Is there any way that these soft references maintained by ojdbc6 driver can be minimized?

Note: Whitepaper by Oracle suggest that the driver maintains a Prepared Statement Cache.

Comment: Change the parameters for garbage collection when initializing the JVM. This should be done in catalina(.bat or .sh, I don't know what you use).

Comment: Had tried -Xmn paramater in JVM to execute frequent GC's.
Using CMS or Parallel Collector showed same result.

One more observation to share- a forecful external GC triggered doesn't frees any references. Though heap dump shows them as Soft Reference.
Am i missing something... any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the additional information.